# android sqlite listview cursor problem

Tags: android, database, sqlite

From my main.java:

```
    Cursor c = db.getDue();

    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "date" };  

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.num, R.id.date };

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.lventer, c, columns, to);
    ListView lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

    lv1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

From my database wrapper class:

```
    public Cursor getDue() {
    //String getdue = "SELECT * FROM tb1"; // this returns _id+date and displays them in the listview via the cursor adapter, defined above
    String getdue = "SELECT _id, max(date) AS date FROM tb1 GROUP BY _id";// this only works if I remove the "date" bindings defined above, only letting me see the _id, i want to see both _id and date in the lit view.

    return db.rawQuery(getdue,null);
```

If I use the second select statment then it crashes unless I remove the "date" from the cursor adapter/listview bindings, if I do this then It will show the returned _id in the listview, but I want to see both _id and date in the listview.

I have been told that the second statment might returns a different type for date because of the max function ( I am not very sql literate, yet), but I thought that sqlite was loose with datatypes? Can anybody help, thanks in advance.

** UPDATE** This is the command that wont work with 2 columns fr the list view:

```
 SELECT _id, max(date) FROM jobs GROUP BY _id HAVING max(date) < (date-21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
String getdue = "SELECT _id, max(date) AS date FROM tb1 GROUP BY _id";
```

Comment: sorry xandy I had pasted the incorrect query into the above code, please check for update.

Comment: I am guessing that the returned column from the query is not "date", but I dont know what it could be since I never constructed the query myself due to lack of sql knowledge, but I have a book ordered!

Comment: SQLite doesn't support Datetime data type. Please refer to this: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime

Comment: Problem may be coming from (date-21), it depends on your declaration of your field, (date-21) should not be understood by the system (or at least not what you would expected).